# Edit form does not auto-fill recently added columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just added 2 new columns to my user table: photo and sex.
For some reason when I create a new user and fill up the entire form(name, photo and sex) it does not stay saved.

When I go to edit it just shows the name I've filled in, but the photo and sex fields are empty everytime.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Here's the form:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, "Full Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :photo_1, "Photo" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :photo_1 %>
</div>
<div class="field"> 
    <%= f.radio_button(:sex, "male") %>
    <%= f.label(:sex, "Male") %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:sex, "female") %>
    <%= f.label(:sex, "Female") %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>`
```

Comment: it would be good if you could post the form html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would rename that column from sex to gender.
Secondly check the attr_accessible declarations on your model, you may need to add these fields to the list

Comment: Doh, I totally forgot about adding them to `attr_accessible`. What would be the proper way to rename the column from `sex` to `gender`?

Comment: you can create a db migration for renaming.

Comment: Could you show me how? I'm new to Rails :< I tried manual migrations but they failed when I tried renaming.

Comment: You will find nearly all you need to know here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html specifically rename_column(table_name, column_name, new_column_name): Renames a column but keeps the type and content.